# realm v field v in terms of

Tags: meaning

As far as I know the words realm and field can have similar meanings but when I read the following [sentence](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-37380429), it made me asking if there was a special purpose for using these two words in the same sentence?

> You can't solve all Europe's problems in one summit. What we have to
>   do is show in our deeds we can do things better in the realms of
>   security and fighting terrorism, and in the field of defence.

Can I shorten the sentence by using only one of them as follows? Is there significant difference between  the original sentence and following sentences in terms of meaning?

1. You can't solve all Europe's problems in one summit. What we have to do is show in our deeds we can do things better **in the realms of** security, fighting terrorism, and defence.
2. You can't solve all Europe's problems in one summit. What we have to do is show in our deeds we can do things better **in the fields of** security,fighting terrorism, and defence.
3. You can't solve all Europe's problems in one summit. What we have to do is show in our deeds we can do things better **in terms of** security, fighting terrorism, and defence.

Comment: In the areas of...  Or with respect to...

Comment: If I were using both *realm* and *field* in the same sentence, I would use *realm* for the wider sphere of interest. Your example seems to do the opposite. It also appears to consider *security* and *fighting terrorism* to be independent of *defence*, My guess would be that the author simply didn't want to use the same word twice.

Answer (score 4):

If we look at the dictionary definitions they are almost synonymous. Especially the applicable definitions of *field* and *realm* read nearly identical and *realm* even uses *field* in its own definition.

*In terms of* is defined a little different in wording but still reads very similar.

> ***field 2:*** A particular branch of study or sphere of activity or interest.  [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/field)
>
> ***realm 1.1:*** A field or domain of activity or interest.  [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/realm)
>
> ***in terms of (or in —— terms):*** With regard to the particular aspect or subject specified.  [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/term)

If we look at the following ngrams we can see that *in terms of* is hugely more used than the other two variants.

[image: field_realm_area_terms]

[image: defense]

[image: security]

While the general dominance of *in terms of* cannot be established with ngrams for the two fields *security* and *defense,* the usage of *realm(s) of)* is always used fewer in the digitized books. Thus, a clear preference for any of the wordings cannot be established. If you want to use a parallelism, I see nothing that precludes you from doing so.

Lastly, note that the sentence is the transcription and translation of something Angela Merkel said. It is not unusual for politicians to add another train of thought after they were almost finished with a sentence. As such the BBC couldn't contract the parallelism without taking some freedom in the translation. However, I see no changing in meaning if they had. Nothing other than making Merkel seem a bit more eloquent at least.

***Update:***

I tracked down the original video. It's on the [Facebook page of the *Bundesregierung*.](https://www.facebook.com/Bundesregierung/videos/1133101143448287/)

> Es geht jetzt nicht darum, einfach von einem Gipfel die Lösung der Probleme Europas zu erwarten. Wir sind in einer kritischen Situation. Sondern es geht darum, durch Taten zu zeigen, dass wir besser werden können: **im Bereich der** Sicherheit - innerer und äußerer Sicherheit - , [bei der] Bekämpfung von Terrorismus und der Zusammenarbeit im Verteidigungs**bereich**, dass wir besser werden können **in den Fragen von** Wachstum und Arbeitsplätzen.

-Angela Merkel, 16.09.2016

She didn't say what's in the brackets, that was inserted by the subtitling on the video. I emphasized her usage of *Bereich*, which is explicitly the same in *im Bereich der Sicherheit ...* (area of security) and *Zusammenarbeit im Verteidigungsbereich* (cooperation in the area of defense). The last is part of a compound word but there's no difference between *Verteidigungsbereich* and *Bereich der Verteidigung.* Generally it's a (very) loose and shortened translation. They even skipped one and a half sentences. Anyways, the use of different words cannot be traced back to the original.

Comment: While I think you've answered the question as stated, I think that an alternative way of them phrasing their sentence to tighten it up, without changing the phrasing too much, would be: 'Europe's problems can't all be solved in one summit. What we have to do is show by our deeds that we can do better in the areas of security, specifically in fighting terrorism, and defence.'

Comment: Yes, fighting terrorism is part of security, which is domestic or internal and tends to be handled by the police while defence is external and tends to be handled by the military.

Grammatically there's no significant difference between realms and fields but logically, realms should include fields and never vice versa. In my memory *realms* is most often used for limitless concepts such as *fantasy* or *imagination*.

Then, I'd been seeking a succinct example such as "*In terms of* his *field* of study, Einstein was highly unusual" to show up that difference.

Comment: Just a thought: if the sentence is the result of translation, perhaps the original words translated as 'realm of' and 'field of' have a definite difference that simply gets lost in translation. As an example using Portuguese (since I don't know German), the English words 'say' and 'tell' are equally translated into 'dizer'.

Comment: @SaraCosta being a native speaker I could easily track it down. She used the same word in both instances. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this was said aloud, so can't be held to the same standards as  carefully edited prose.

My best guess is that Mrs Merkel said it that way, not because there is a significant difference between *realm* and *field*, but because she wanted to group the first two as a single item:

> You can't solve all Europe's problems in one summit. What we have to do is show in our deeds we can do things better in the realm(s) of (security and fighting terrorism), and in the (field of defence).

This seems plausible, since "fighting terrorism" is usually seen a subset of "security", while "defense" usually refers to traditional military/border issues.

Interpreted this way, *realm* should have been singular.

As for why she didn't use the same term (realm or field) for both, she might have simply been trying not to be repetitive.

If my interpretation is correct, then all your versions that combine the 3 items into a single list do not capture the original intent.

**EDIT**: I just saw the sentence was a translation. This makes things more complicated, but may just push some of these word choices onto the translator, instead of the original speaker.